# How to fire a function immediately?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm going to display a "please enable javascript" message to my site which will be hidden by javascript.

-> WORKS!

-> PROBLEM:

I use Dojo so I tried with dojo.addOnLoad, but the message will not dissapear immediately after you visit the site, it will disapear when the site finished loading.
That sucks for users which actually have js enabled, because the message will be visible to them.
So it seems like I missed smthing very basically.

please help!
Thx in advance!

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's actually a good question. I can not answer it however, I have always ran js in the body.onLoad() function which means that it runs after the site has loaded. Maybe that's always the case?

Comment: Probably a dislike to using a 2004 toolkit to solve a problem that had been dealt with in 1996 when netscape Navigator 2 introduced the `<noscript>` element along side the `<script>`element. Still, I'd give that as an answer (had SLaks not already done so) rather than downvoting.

Comment: Latest Dojo relase was june of this year ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put the message in a `<noscript>` tag.